# Ruby Vs. C# - Better for Game Programming

Tags: c#, ruby

I have seen some games made in C#, such as using the XNA. I saw some games made in Ruby by using the RGSS1-3 API as well. I just can't decide on my own which would be easier to learn and apply for game programming. I want your opinion on which is better to make games with, is it Ruby or C#? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: "Which technology is better?" and "Which language should I learn?" questions are off topic as written in the [FAQ]. The links on those points explain why.

Comment: Define some specific technical requirements, then ask if specific languages and tools meet those specific requirements. There's also some questions about ruby on this site, use the search feature.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: offtopic: aaa games aren't written in any such languages. If you want to experiment and aren't performance crazy, then pick either.

Comment: Actually, Stronghold Kingdoms is in C#, and it could border on AAA ;) There are many famous indie games in C#, like Bastion, Magicka, Terraria or Sol Survivor; for indies C# is a valid choice due to XBLA. And of course there is Unity, which uses C# as a 'scripting' language.

I don't know any well-know games made in Ruby, and I think it just isn't as widely supported, especially with regard to different platforms.

Comment: Hell, Sims 3 uses C# (although not exclusively), and if "such languages" includes the likes of python or lua, I can then point to everything from WoW to EvE Online to Civilization 4 as using them.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the very valid point Liosan makes about being able to make Unity games, Another really nifty advantage of C# is the ability to use the [MonoGame framework](https://www.monogame.net) to (as they put it)  *"...allow XNA developers on Xbox 360, Windows & Windows Phone to port their games to the iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux and Windows 8 Metro.  PlayStation Mobile development is currently in progress."*

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I've removed the signatures from your answers as they aren't needed and just clutter up the answers. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) for more details.